# i want to add this tailwind style ( active:border-b-2 active:border-blue-500) in next.js but this doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, next.js

this is the tailwind style which i want to add

```js
import React from 'react'

function HeaderIcon({Icon}) {
  return (
    <div
      className="flex
      items-center
      cursor-pointer
      md:px-10
      sm:h-14
      md:hover:bg-gray-100
      rounded-xl
      active:border-b-2
      active:border-blue-500"
    >
      <Icon className="h-5" />
    </div>
  )
}

export default HeaderIcon
```

------here i want to add tailwind style-----------------------------

```html
<div className="flex justify-center flex-grow">
  <div className="flex space-x-6 md:space-2">
    <HeaderIcon Icon={HomeIcon} />
    <HeaderIcon Icon={FlagIcon} />
    <HeaderIcon Icon={PlayIcon} />
    <HeaderIcon Icon={ShoppingCartIcon} />
    <HeaderIcon Icon={UserGroupIcon} />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The [`:active`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active) pseudo-class probably has not effect on a `div` element, it's usually used on `<a>` and `<button>` elements (elements that contain an activated element).

Comment: Not reproducible with the current information - https://play.tailwindcss.com/iXlWKLbAyc. Can you show us your tailwind config? You need to enable `'active'` variants of [`border-width`](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/border-width#variants) and [`border-color`](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/border-color#variants) if you're not using [JIT mode](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/just-in-time-mode).

Comment: now it works fine my jit compiler doesn't workout properly and now it works very fine thanks bro for reviewing my problem

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify the Tailwind settings to enable the **active** status.

[Documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#active)

```js
// tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
  // ...
  variants: {
    extend: {
      backgroundColor: ['active'],
    }
  },
}
```

Comment: tried it but it doesn't work